# Альтернатива echo - PHP

Tags: php

Ищу альтернативы echo, которые будут нести меньшую нагрузку на сервер.

Comment: что значит меньшую нагрузку????? Все "альтернативы" делают одно и тоже

Comment: А чем echo не угодил? Самая простая функция. Альтернатива - использование шаблонизаторов.

Comment: Дело в том, что я пишу скрипт с очень большим количеством вывода информации с помощью echo. Хотелось бы снизить нагрузку на сервер, поэтому и ищу альтернативы.

Comment: Консольный скрипт?

Comment: Что вам не нравится? Ну попробуйте print(),printf();! 
Есть намного ресурсоёмкие запросы, чем уделать внимание этому=))

Comment: Вопрос типа "что быстрее: `$a += 2;` или `++$a;++$a;`". =) Попробуйте буфер, как описано ниже, либо формирование кода страницы с последующим выводом его одним куском (что, по сути, одно и то же).

Comment: да уж, глобальная проблема, я бы сказал..

Comment: Недавно это здесь обсуждали, сравнивали print и echo. Победило (если память не изменяет) echo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вначале скрипта напиши ob_start()
Там, где всё уже готово и страница должна отправиться в браузер напиши ob_end_flush()
И оставь echo.

Comment: это не уменьшит "нагрузку" на сервер

Comment: Я тоже всегда был уверен в этом. Но на самом деле разница получается колоссальная порой. Просто в начале скрипта писал $t1 = microtime(true), в конце echo(round(microtime(true) - $t1, 7)); Когда много-много хтмл с большим количеством раскрывающихся списков - порой выигрышь за счёт буферизации был в десятки раз. Правда. Потестите. Сделайте страничку с кучей селектов, с кучей опций в каждом и выводите всё это с помощью echo, но не собирая всё в переменную и потом одним echo, а для каждой опции своё echo и т.п.

Comment: Вы не учитываете транспортные расходы. `echo` делает вывод в браузер. Какая разница между доставкой браузеру маленьких кусков информации и одного большого пакета?

Comment: Спасибо, попробую.

Comment: @KiTE, echo - это { получение указателя, определение длины строки, чтение (копирование, между прочим) переменной, запись строки в сокет }. Вот и смотрите разницу между сотней операций и одной.

Comment: Буфферизация через буффер-переменную - это тоже получение указателя на источник, определение длины строки-источника, чтение, копирование в приемник.

Comment: Да, только операция одна) 

    for ($i = 0; $i < 1000; $i++)
      $x += 2;

VS

    $x += 2000;

Если вы не об этом, конкатенация - намного более дешевая операция, чем вывод.

Comment: @KiTE, собственно, <a href="http://sh4dow.jino.ru/buffertest.php">вот</a>. На случай потери скрипта, 100000 операций, без буфера 0.314 сек, с буфером 0.009 сек.

Comment: Да, интересный результат, спасибо за инфу!

Comment: вопрос конечно интересный, но это разговор о высоких материях бытия...<br>
Откровенно говоря очень сильно сомневаюсь что аффтар копает в нужную сторону, @Sh4dow - слабо верится в том что у аффтара 100000 операций и это мягко говоря, а если у него столько операций не стоит ли задуматся о том как уменьшить их количество?<br>
Вообще вопрос интересный, но о5 таки повторюсь - не думаю что автор копает в нужную сторону, echo нагружает сервер? это что-то страшное :D<br>

Comment: @KiTE, "Вы не учитываете транспортные расходы. echo делает вывод в браузер. Какая разница между доставкой браузеру маленьких кусков информации и одного большого пакета?"

Колоссальная. Вы не учитываете накладные расходы **каждого** системного вызова + увеличение сетевого трафика и связанного с этим количеством прерываний.

Answer (score 2):

Вы замеры скорости делали? Ибо ваше утверждение сродни вымыслу.

Comment: Говорю же, <strong>пишу</strong>. Еще там около тысячи строк кода надо написать... Поэтому сейчас замеры скорости делать бессмысленно.

Comment: Если вы знакомы с возможностью "Найти&Заменить" из любого текстового редактора, то советую вам отложить этот вопрос, имхо - ерунда, до момента когда вы заметите проблемы со скоростью, ибо ускорять то - чего нет, эмм... трудно)))

Comment: Я знаком с такой функцией. :) Ничего не поменялось бы, если бы я задал этот вопрос через некоторое время или сейчас. Даже, наверное, сейчас лучше, потому как мог бы забыть, дел ведь много, всего и не упомнишь...

Comment: Повторю: **"ускорять то - чего нет, эмм... трудно)))"**<br>
Сколько-бы вы не раскрашивали невидимого розового единорога, вы не увидите результатов своих действий!

Comment: Все таки, сделайте маленький (количество строк) и очень объемный (много повторений цикла) тест (минут за 10) и замерьте время.

Answer (score 0):

по мере работы скрипта складывай всё в переменную, а потом один раз echo в конце скрипта

Comment: Спасибо за совет, но у меня так не выйдет. В любом случае надо несколько раз echo использовать.

Comment: Неудачный вариант, если человек говорит о выгрузке больших объемов информации. Переменная будет лежать в памяти, а обычный `echo` делает вывод в STDOUT

Answer (score 0):

Самый быстрый способ вывести информацию - <<<.

Пример:

```
echo <<<KEYWORD
Lorem Ipsum
KEYWORD;
```

Такой текст не подвергается обработке. Просто выплевывается.
Ну и плюс как советует [[@OlegSobachnik](/users/4659/olegsobachnik)](/users/4659/olegsobachnik). использовать буффер.

Answer (score 0):

Кстати, а чем плоха такая вставка:

```
    <?php
    $a = 12;
    ?>
    <div><?=$a?></div>
    <?php
    $r = $a;
    ?>
```

А то пользуюсь, а вдруг это очень дурной тон и много минусов в этом способе...